# Array populated witin 'service' but empty when referenced by any 'controller'

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have an AngularJS `service` which should get a JSON object and create three arrays based on differing criteria (all, searchable and has coordinates).  These arrays need to be referenced by more than one `controller`, hence the use of a `service`.

When I test any of the three arrays the array within the `service` itself (as below), all three are correctly populated.

However, all three of my arrays are empty when referenced by any `controller`.

What am I missing here?

```
app.service('$stationsList', ['$http', function($http){

    var stationsList = [],
        searchableStations = [],
        locatableStations = [];
    
    $http.get('stations.json').then(function(res){  // Grab the JSON list of all stations
        
        [].map.call(res.data || [], function(elm){  // Map all stations...
        
            stationsList = res.data;            // Set all stations to 'stationsList'
            
            if(elm.link.indexOf(".xml") > -1)   // Check to see if the station is searchable (has a full link)
                searchableStations.push(elm);   // It does - add the station to 'searchableStations'
                
            if(                                 // Check to see if the station can be checked as the closest station (has coordinates)
            isFinite(parseFloat(elm.latitude)) &&
            isFinite(parseFloat(elm.longitude))
            )
                locatableStations.push(elm);    // It does - add the station to 'locatableStations'
        });

        console.log(stationsList);
        console.log(searchableStations);
        console.log(locatableStations);
        
    });
    
    return{
        
        getList: function(){
            return stationsList;
        },
        setList: function(value){
            stationsList = value;
        },
        
        getSearchable: function(){
            return searchableStations;
        },
        setSearchable: function(value){
            searchableStations = value;
        },
        
        getLocatable: function(){
            return locatableStations;
        },
        setLocatable: function(value){
            locatableStations = value;
        }
        
    };
    
}]);
```

Example of how I'm referencing service -

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$localStorage', '$stationsList', function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $stationsList){

    $scope.stationsList = $stationsList.getSearchable();    // Grab a list of all stations
    $scope.selectStation = click_selectStation;             // Handle clicks of a station within the 'searchCtrl' controller
    $scope.localStorage = $localStorage.$default({          // Grab the local storage (so that it can be updated when the user selects a station)
        recentStations: []                                  // Set a default value of '[]' for recentStations in case it doesn't exist
    });
    
}]);
```

---

## Edit

Derived from the answer posted by **PankajParkar** below, here is the `service` that will return the three arrays that I require.

However, my issue here is that every call to a method within the service triggers another async call to `$http.get` my JSON data.  This is exactly what I was trying to avoid by using a `service`.

My desired outcome is one JSON call per page load, with my 3 arrays being created from that JSON call and then accessible to my controllers as and when required.  If a `service` is not the correct answer, I am certainly open to other suggestions.

```
app.service('$stationsList', ['$http', function($http){

    var searchableStations = [],
        locatableStations = [];
    
    /**
     * Grab all stations (for the master list)
     */
    var getAllStations = function(){
    
        return $http.get('stations.json').then(function(res){   // Grab the JSON list of all stations
            return res.data;
        });
        
    };
    
    /**
     * Grab only searchable stations (those with full links)
     */
    var getSearchableStations = function(){
    
        return $http.get('stations.json').then(function(res){   // Grab the JSON list of all stations
        
            [].map.call(res.data || [], function(elm){  // Map all stations...
            
                if (elm.link.indexOf(".xml") > -1)  // Check to see if the station is searchable
                    searchableStations.push(elm);   // It is - add the station to 'searchableStations'
            });
            
            return searchableStations;
            
        });
    };
    
    /**
     * Grab only locatable stations (those with coordinates)
     */
    var getLocatableStations = function(){
    
        return $http.get('stations.json').then(function(res){ // Grab the JSON list of all stations
        
            [].map.call(res.data || [], function(elm){  // Map all stations...
            
                if(
                isFinite(parseFloat(elm.latitude)) &&
                isFinite(parseFloat(elm.longitude))
                )                                   // Check to see if the station is locatable
                    locatableStations.push(elm);    // It is - add the station to 'locatableStations'
            });
            
            return locatableStations;
            
        });
    };
    
    return{
        getAll:         getAllStations,
        getSearchable:  getSearchableStations,
        getLocatable:   getLocatableStations
    };
    
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is failing because you made asynchronous ajax call & accepting value as soon as it made. That's why you are getting your values as undefined.

You need to wait till your ajax gets completed, that could be implemented using returning ajax promise to controller from service. So i'd suggest you to create a new method which will do `$http` ajax and will return promise from that function & that will execute `.then` function of controller that called the `getSearchableStations`. Below snippet will give you an Idea what I wanted to say.

**Service**

```
app.service('$stationsList', ['$http', function($http) {

    var stationsList = [],
        searchableStations = [],
        locatableStations = [];

    var getSearchableStations = function() {
        return $http.get('stations.json').then(function(res) { // Grab the JSON list of all stations

            [].map.call(res.data || [], function(elm) { // Map all stations...

                stationsList = res.data; // Set all stations to 'stationsList'

                if (elm.link.indexOf(".xml") > -1) // Check to see if the station is searchable (has a full link)
                    searchableStations.push(elm); // It does - add the station to 'searchableStations'

                if ( // Check to see if the station can be checked as the closest station (has coordinates)
                    isFinite(parseFloat(elm.latitude)) &&
                    isFinite(parseFloat(elm.longitude))
                )
                    locatableStations.push(elm); // It does - add the station to 'locatableStations'
            });

            console.log(stationsList);
            console.log(searchableStations);
            console.log(locatableStations);
            return locatableStations; //return data from here.
        });
    };

    return {

        getList: function() {
            return stationsList;
        },
        setList: function(value) {
            stationsList = value;
        },

        getSearchable: function() {
            return searchableStations;
        },
        setSearchable: function(value) {
            searchableStations = value;
        },

        getLocatable: function() {
            return locatableStations;
        },
        setLocatable: function(value) {
            locatableStations = value;
        },
        //added new function
        getSearchableStations: getSearchableStations
    };

}]);
```

Inside you controller you will call service `getSearchableStations` method that does return promise, You will use `.then` function that would get called when promise get resolved. Same has been shown below with code.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$localStorage', '$stationsList', 
   function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $stationsList){

    $stationsList.getSearchableStations().then(function(data){
    $scope.stationsList = data;
    $scope.selectStation = click_selectStation;             // Handle clicks of a station within the 'searchCtrl' controller
       $scope.localStorage = $localStorage.$default({          // Grab the local storage (so that it can be updated when the user selects a station)
          recentStations: []                                  // Set a    default value of '[]' for recentStations in case it doesn't exist
       });
    });    // Grab a list of all stations
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you have done.  You seem to have done away with the service I implimented, and the three distinct lists that I require seem to be a little mixed up. It may be that I am misunderstanding your answer, so any further comments/explaination what be apprciated.

Comment: @DavidGard could you look at my udpated answer..it should be clear now..let me know if you want anything else from me

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand.  I don't doubt your knowledge,  your reputation suggests you know your stuff, but I can't work out in my head where you want me to place the `Service` code, and also what you are referring to with `//....other code`.  Everything I try with your example generates errors (usually that I'm trying to use `.then` on an undefined variable).

Comment: let me update an answer..with how your service will look like

Comment: Thank you, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidGard actually that was my bad..Sorry for that..do look at update in `service` and `controller` code too..It should work now

Comment: Thanks for the update, it did indeed work.  However, I'd be greatful if you could see the edits to my question as, while your solution works, it throws up the issue of an external JSON file being accesed multiple times, which is what I was trying to avoid by using a `service` in the first place.  +1 for your generous efforts thus far.